# usdz_converter not picking up materials

Tags: arkit, usdz

I am hoping someone can shed some light on why the usdz_converter is not picking up the materials specified. When running the following command

```
xcrun usdz_converter ~/Desktop/demo/demo.obj ~/Desktop/demo/demo.usdz -v -a -l -m /Materials/Material_001 -color_map blk.jpg
```

in the root of the directory where my demo.obj and blk.jpg files live, the USDZ file is generated but without the specified materials applied to it.

```
usdz_converter
Version: 1.008

-v: Verbose output
-a: Generate .usda intermediate file
-l: Leave generated .usda file
-m:
    /Materials/Material_001
-color_map: blk.jpg


Primitives:
    Transform: /xrdslogo
    Transform: /xrdslogo/Geom
    GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_005
        bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_002
    GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_004
        bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_001
    GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_003
        bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_004
    GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_002
        bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_003
    GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_Cube_001
        bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_006
    GeomScope: /xrdslogo/Materials
    ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_002
    ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_001
    ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_004
    ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_003
    ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_006
```

Below is what is printed in the terminal

```
usdz_converter  
Version: 1.008  

-v: Verbose output  
-a: Generate .usda intermediate file  
-l: Leave generated .usda file  
-m:  
  /Materials/Material_001  
-color_map: blk.jpg  


Primitives:  
  Transform: /xrdslogo  
  Transform: /xrdslogo/Geom  
  GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_005  
  bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_002  
  GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_004  
  bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_001  
  GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_003  
  bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_004  
  GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_002  
  bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_003  
  GeomMesh: /xrdslogo/Geom/Cube_Cube_001  
  bound material: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_006  
  GeomScope: /xrdslogo/Materials  
  ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_002  
  ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_001  
  ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_004  
  ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_003  
  ShadeMaterial: /xrdslogo/Materials/Material_006
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add object name on start of material name: -m /xrdslogo//Materials/Material_001